# List the extensions *enabled* in Safari for Mac OS X

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List the extensions installed in Safari for Mac OS X, and state whether each one is enabled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39240/list-the-extensions-installed-in-safari-for-mac-os-x-and-state-whether-each-one)

I'd like a list, from which text can be copied.

(Not a screenshot of preferences.)

This information does not appear in any of the following:

- Safari
- System Profiler in Snow Leopard
- System Information in Lion.

Comment: Please do not close this question. My recent edition to the other question explains why the two are separate. Thanks.

Comment: Actually they ain't different, the answer is the same in both cases. And looking forward, future users will be better served by one question covering both aspects.

Comment: Moderators: I'm now very pleasantly surprised by the answer from patrix in the other question. The other question is adapted, please go ahead and close this one. Thanks.